# Nginx Regex Directing Specific Requests For Custom Blog

Tags: php, regex, nginx

## **BACKGROUND**

> Our website has a blog subsection that runs off a simple custom-made CMS. I'm using Nginx as a webserver, PHP as the back-end language.
>
> The blog index is /news, which contains dynamic links to each post. Clicking one of these links directs the user to /blog/post-title. I'm using Nginx to intercept any request to the post template page located in the /blog folder.
>
> Here's the basic flow
>
> #### 1. User clicks blog with link to `/blog/post-title`
>
> #### 2. Nginx catches this request and serves it to `/blog/index`, which is our template
>
> #### 3. The post is displayed with the url `https://www.domain.com/blog/post-title`

## **My Problem**

I would like to change the blog index from `/news` to `/blog`, but doing so causes anchors to direct to the file `/blog` rather than the folder `/blog/`.

Here is the current Nginx configuration

```
location /blog/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?$args;
}
```

## TL;DR

I need nginx to catch and direct requests directed toward the folder /blog/ while ignoring the file /blog.php

Answer (score 0):

This is a long shot as I'm not sure how the files are layout on your server but give this a try.

```
location ~ ^/blog/(.*)$ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?$1;
}
```